# Getting error for invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT emp. email_01 as online_id,
            emp. email_02 as primary_id,
            dept. email_03 as secondary_id
from 
(select distinct
           emp. email_01 as online_id,
            emp. email_02 as primary_id,
            dept. email_03 as secondary_id
    from emp, dept
    where emp.id=dept.id)
```

Comment: yes I do, can you show me how to do it,

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, [ask] and  [mcve] can be useful to improve your question

Comment: Ok, Do you have any suggestion regarding my query ?

Comment: If the query is EXACTLY as you show in your post, then the error is very likely caused by the spaces you have after the period `.` between table and column names.

Comment: @mathguy.. Error is `invalid identifier` .. Which is due to aliasing .

Comment: @XING - I agree. I just tested and to my surprise, `select emp . empno from scott . emp` works perfectly fine, with spaces on either side of the dot. So that couldn't have been the error - it is syntactically correct.

Comment: Hello why I am ban to post new questions, how do I resolve this issue

Comment: You have (likely) been banned because you refuse to respect the rules. You post bad questions and refuse to edit them to clarify, format or improve in any way. When you get an answer you refuse to accept or upvote; when people asks you to improve your questions or accept the answers you say something like "Yes I will click accept today" or Can I suggest your .Net developer to create a button for when Accept". Read the links that people gave you on how to answer, format, handle the answers. This way you'll post better questions, have good answers and upvotes and contribute to improve SO.

Comment: Give me one example of bad question? so I can correct myself.

Comment: This questions has got a score of -4, for example; or any of your downvoted questions; ora questions where people asked you to better format, add informations, clarify, ...

Comment: Who provide this score, your company. right ?

Comment: You seem confused about [how SO works](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have a sub-query in this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       emp.email_01  AS online_id,
       emp.email_02  AS primary_id,
       dept.email_03 AS secondary_id
FROM   emp
       INNER JOIN dept
       ON ( emp.id=dept.id )
```

You can also use the ANSI join syntax rather than the (confusing) legacy Oracle comma-join syntax.